# Formatting Dates on x-axis in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, graphing

I'm using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) and I know this topic is covered quite a bit in the [docs](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-AxisValueFormatter-interface), so apologies if I've missed something obvious, but I'm having a bit of trouble formatting timestamp values into dates on the x-axis of my Linechart.

It appears that getFormattedValue() isn't being invoked for my x-axis value for whatever reason. If i debug AxisBase, it only seems to looking to format the y-axis values, which i do not have a custom formatter set on.

Here is the code snippets, taken mostly from the Github docs:

```
          LineChart chart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
          XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();

          // set min timestamp to Jul 2017 
          HourAxisValueFormatter(Long.parseLong("1499814559"));

          xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
             // THIS IS NEVER INVOKED!
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) 
            {
                return new Date(Long.parseLong(""+value)).toString();
            }
        });

        // rating is a map of timestamp to numeric value, both stored 
        // as strings
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> rating : ratings.entrySet()) {
            String timestamp = rating.getKey();
            String ratingValue = rating.getValue();
            entries.add(new Entry(Float.parseFloat(timestamp), 
            Float.parseFloat(ratingValue)));
        }

            // add entries to dataset
            LineDataSet dataSet = new LineDataSet(entries, "Ratings");
            LineData lineData = new LineData(dataSet);
            chart.setData(lineData);
            chart.invalidate(); // refresh'
```

I'm using version 3.0.2 of the library:

`compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'`

Thanks in advance, Gary

EDIT per request for desired output/actual output: 
Ideally i would have a series of dates along the x-axis , e.g. 10/7, 11/8, 12/8, etc. constructed from the Epoch values I've provided. I know the code above wont format it in that format as it stands, but just want to get it formatting to any date value initially (so ignore that for now), the crux of the issue is that my formatter isn't getting invoked at all.

Below is a screenshot of the current output, it only prints a single value on the x=0 line (note even though there are multiple y values being provided, i wonder if they are all on the same x=0 line does it just draw the last point or something?):

[image]

Debugging the timestamp values above, Float.parseFloat(timestamp) is equal to 1.50516885e^12. The actual timestamp value for example is 1505168846751, but after parsing to a Float is rounded, and given an exponent value.

EDIT 2 :

Screen grab of the values supplied as 'entries' to the LineDataSet:

[image]

EDIT 3: 
The issue appears to be to do with the size/format of the timestamp values for the x-values I'm providing, changing these to small float values in the range 1.0 -> 20.0f, causes the formatter to be invoked as expected. I need to debug the code further to see why the exponential timestamp values are not being formatted.

Comment: can you please share your required output and your output from your code.

Comment: Hi @MehulKabaria , I've provided some more information there, hopefully it makes sense. Let me know if i can provide more details. Apologies for the size of the image, zooming is causing a crash at the moment, but i think you get the idea :)

Comment: what date format is required from timestamp please provide that

Comment: The date format isnt really a concern for me at the moment, what i have above is just new Date(timestamp).toString(), which is fine for the moment, the problem is that this formatter isnt getting called at all - ideally the x-axis would have dates in the format dd/MM

Comment: See EDIT 3 above, it appears the timestamp values are causing the issue, changing these to smaller values means the formatter gets invoked as expected. I need to debug the code to understand why this is the case.

Comment: I think with Entry only accepting float constructor params, i am kind of limited here. When it tries to work out the range of the x-axis [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/6f1d365176251a70adee6da5da494ad43c0dd050/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer/AxisRenderer.java#L155) it is returning 0, since there isn't high enough precision in these values. It is the exponent values which are causing the issue. Thanks Mehul and Amit for your comments anyway

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From looking into this i think this is a limitation at the moment, for this specific use case (timestamps are very close together) since Entry will only accept floating point values, my timestamps are all getting passed as 1.50516885e^12, even though the precise timestamp values are slightly different. When AxisRenderer works out the range for the x-axis then is sees it as 0, and sets the entries to 0 also, in this block [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/6f1d365176251a70adee6da5da494ad43c0dd050/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer/AxisRenderer.java#L157)

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: As far as i can remember this was a silly fault on my own part, where I was working out the epoch incorrectly, thinking it was the number of milliseconds instead of the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970. I think this resulted in the range being worked out to 0, and so no formatter was applied. Check your data to make sure you have a distinct range in your x-axis values.